# Error visual studio 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, .net, visual-studio-2013

Acabo de migrar un proyecto de visual 2010 a 2013, y comprobando si todo estaba bien, me salta este error:

> Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.BadImageFormatException' en
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Información adicional: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado
>   'AForge.Video.FFMPEG, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=03563089b1be05dd' ni una de sus dependencias. Se ha
>   intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.

¿Alguien sabe cómo lo puedo solucionar? He intentado importar las librerías de nuevo, pero no sé solucióna.

Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Ese error es una incompatibilidad entre una aplicacion de 32bits tratando de cargar una libreria de 64bits o al reves. Comprueba que tipo de plataforma tienes en tu aplicacion, si la versión de la libreria `AForge.Video.FFMPEG` es de 32 o 64 bits y que sistema operativo tienes.

**Edit**

Tras consultarlo, parece que no hay version de 64bits de la libreria `AForge.Video.FFMPEG`, con lo que tendrás que compilar tu proyecto en 32 bits.

**Edit2**

Pues si que hay version de 64 bits. Puedes descargarlo [desde aqui](https://aforgeffmpeg.codeplex.com/releases/view/114463)

Comment: Antes, el proyecto estaba en 32 bits en 2010, ahora lo he subido todo a 64 bits y a 2012. Tengo que actualizar las librerias imagino no?

Comment: Efectivamente. Tendrás que actualizar las referencias de las librerias a su version de 64 bits

Comment: Creo que hay de 64 bits, porque tengo otro proyecto compilado en 64 con esas librerias

Comment: el tema es que ya las habia descargado, e importado al proyecto, pero me sigue saliendo ese error. Voy a hacer un par de comprobaciones, y con cualquier cosa, te comento.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que debes referenciar las dlls de la carpeta `AForge.Video.FFMPEG-2.2.5_x64_DOTNETFX4` , o sea, las x64

Comment: Echa tambien un vistazo a [este enlace](https://bydaniel.wordpress.com/2017/05/01/aforge-net-ffmpeg/)

Comment: Ya he probado todo, he referenciado las librerias, y todo, y me sigue sin funcionar :s

Comment: Viste el enlace que te puse en mi comentario anterior? Seguiste los pasos que se indican ahi?

Comment: Si si, pero nada

Comment: Tu sistema operativo imagino que es de 64 bits?. Pues sin tener acceso a la solución no puedo ayudarte mas me temo. El error viene provocado porque tu solución debe seguir intentando cargar las dll's de 32 bits...

Comment: ya, eso he visto... seguire intentando cosas, y cuando encuentre la solucion, edito la pregunta.  Gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Ahora que me acabo de fijar, puede ser que como he subido al framework 4, y antes estaba en 2, sea por eso?

Comment: Podria ser. Como ya te dije anteriormente, las dll's deben ser las de la carpeta `AForge.Video.FFMPEG-2.2.5_x64_DOTNETFX4` (fijate en el `DOTNETFX4`)

Comment: Es que uso otras dll de aforge, pero no las he podido encontrar :S , estoy en ello

Comment: Hola @Pikoh , despues de un dia probando, preguntando a compañeros, me sigue dando el error :S

Comment: Como ya te dije @urrutias es dificil ayudarte sin tener acceso a la solucion. Intenta crear una solucion muy simple que reproduzca el problema y subela a algun sitio donde podamos descargarla y probarla a ver si asi vemos el problema